# Show a brief description of a column family in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, limit

For example, I have data already stored into Cassandra's **column family** `playerinfo` of **keyspace** `info`

In `cqlsh`, is there a way to show a brief description of that column family? It can show me how many keys and columns under keys are already stored in that column family.

PS: The problem I am now facing is that my program should keep pushing data into Cassandra, but I noticed that it seems no more records are stored successfully after a certain amount of time. So I want to check if the content of the column family changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to do it from within cqlsh, but from a command prompt you should be able to get that information by doing a `nodetool cfstats`:

```
$ nodetool cfstats myKeyspace.myColumnFamily
Keyspace: myKeyspace
        Read Count: 3
        Read Latency: 3.552 ms.
        Write Count: 8
        Write Latency: 0.321375 ms.
        Pending Tasks: 0
                Table: myColumnFamily
                SSTable count: 1
                Space used (live), bytes: 6724
                Space used (total), bytes: 6724
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.2571466917192323
                Number of keys (estimate): 128
                Memtable cell count: 0
                Memtable data size, bytes: 0
                Memtable switch count: 1
                Local read count: 3
                Local read latency: 0.000 ms
                Local write count: 8
                Local write latency: 0.000 ms
                Pending tasks: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 0
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used, bytes: 16
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 6867
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 8239
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 8239
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 5.0
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 6.0
```

So in your case, try `$ nodetool cfstats info.playerinfo` and see if that gives you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following command which will give the full description of your columnfamily.

> DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILY keyspace.columnfamily(info.playerinfo);

it will give list of all the columns including the primary key,secondary indexes everything.

like below.

> cqlsh:events> DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILY events.standardevents1103;
>
> CREATE TABLE standardevents1103 (   uuid uuid PRIMARY KEY,   data
>   text,   name text,   time text,   tracker text,   type text,   userid
>   text ) WITH
>    bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
>   caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND   comment='' AND
>   dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND 
>     gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND 
>   read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
>      replicate_on_write='true' AND
>   populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
>    compaction={'class':
>   'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
>   compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};